# How to find max and min numbers in list within list

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, replace, return

I am stuck at this question where I am required to update all largest and smallest numbers in the list with the average value as a way to remove the extreme values in the given list.

For example:

`def remove_extreme( [ [0,4], [1,4], [-1,2] ] )` would `return [ [0,1.5], [1,1.5], [1.5,2] ]`.

The function will need to use the average value to modify the elements in the lists, which, in this case the smallest and largest values are -1 and 4 respectively. Then, all the largest and smallest values present in the list need to be changed to the average(mean) of these two values, which is (4+-1)/2 = 1.5

Here's my code:

```
def remove_extreme(datalist):
    for numlist in datalist:
        for index, number in enumerate(numlist):
            largest = max(number)
            smallest = min(number)
            average = (largest - smallest)/2
            if number == largest or smallest:
                num_list[index] = average
        return datalist
```

May I know what went wrong? I keep getting 'int' object is not iterable.

Comment: to get `largest` and `smallest` you are doing `max(number)` and `min(number)` but `number` is just - well - a number... you probably want to do `max(numlist)` **outside** of the inner loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What you asked about

To answer your immediate question, the built in functions `max` and `min` return for you the maximum and minimum number from an iterable.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max

So it throws a `TypeError` when you pass it an integer. Run it on a list/iterable instead.

But your code has more issues than just that.

Your `if` statement, though syntactically correct, is probably not what you want. More than likely you wanted to do this:

```py
if number == largest or number == smallest:
```

Like Tomerikoo pointed out, you want to put your `max` and `min` outside the loop. As an aside, you do not need to return the list as lists are mutable and you are modifying it freely inside the function.

```py
def remove_extreme(datalist):
    for numlist in datalist:
        largest = max(numlist)
        smallest = min(numlist)
        average = (largest - smallest)/2
        for index, number in enumerate(numlist):
            if number == largest or number == smallest:
                numlist[index] = average
    return datalist
```

### What your problem is actually asking you

Looking at your original question I think you're a little off from the correct answer if your lists need to look like your given answer. The first hint is that your given answer shows only one of the values changed, and it's not always the average of the inner list. Take `[0, 4]` for instance. `1.5` is not the average of 0 and 4, yet that is what you say it should return. It seems that you are really desiring to change the most extreme number for each inner list based off the average of all the lists. Taking the average of the numbers of all the inner lists yields `1.66`, so I'm not sure of this precisely, but I think one of your numbers might be off by 1 (I think so because 10/6 yields 1.66 while 9/6 yields 1.5).

If the above assumptions are all correct you will want to calculate the average (which is usually the `sum/number of elements`) and then find the most extreme element within each list.

Your function should look a bit more like this:

```py
def remove_extreme(datalist):
    # sum len of each list to get total number of elements
    num_elements = sum([len(numlist) for numlist in datalist])
    # sum the sum of each list to get total
    sum_elements = sum([sum(numlist) for numlist in datalist])
    # calculate average
    average = sum_elements/num_elements
    # find the most extreme element in each list and perform substitution
    for numlist in datalist:
        smallest = min(numlist)
        largest = max(numlist)
        large_diff = abs(largest - average)
        small_diff = abs(average - smallest)
        num_to_change = largest if large_diff > small_diff else smallest
        for index, number in enumerate(numlist):
            if number == num_to_change: # Just look at the most extreme number
                numlist[index] = average
    return datalist # list will be modified, but returning it doesn't hurt either
```

Running this function after changing your `-1` to `-2`:

```py
my_list = [
    [0,4],
    [1,4],
    [-2,2]
]

print("Before: ", my_list)
remove_extreme(my_list)
print("After: ", my_list)
```

Output:

```
$ python remove_extreme.py 
Before:  [[0, 4], [1, 4], [-2, 2]]
After:  [[0, 1.5], [1, 1.5], [1.5, 2]]
```

### After further clarification

After clarifying what the question was **really** asking you, the answer is even simpler:

```py
def remove_extreme(datalist):
    flattened = [i for numlist in datalist for i in numlist] # flatten list for convenience
    largest = max(flattened)
    smallest = min(flattened)
    average = (largest + smallest)/2
    # find the most extreme element in each list and perform substitution
    for numlist in datalist:
        for index, number in enumerate(numlist):
            if number == smallest or number == largest:
                numlist[index] = average
    return datalist # list will be modified, but returning it doesn't hurt either
```

Personally I feel like this makes less sense, but that seems to be what you're asking for.

Also, when writing a question, it's helpful to include the stack trace or point to the specific line where the issue is occurring. Just a helpful tip!

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for such a detailed answer! Just to clarify, the function will need to return the average value of the largest and smallest number in the given list, which, in this case is -1 and 4. Then, all the largest and smallest values present in the list need to be changed to the average(mean) of these two values, which is (4+-1)/2 = 1.5. Hope that clarifies! And thanks for the tip, I'm a total newbie here so it's very warming to see someone showing the way! :) I'll edit the details of the question soon.

Comment: Ahh, yes, please try to be precise when asking your questions as that makes the solution completely different. I will update my answer (but keep what I had written) given what you have said. Additionally, you do not mean that it "will need to return the average value" but that it uses that average value to modify the elements in the lists.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get max and min of the element not of the list

```
>>> list = ( [ [0,4], [1,4], [-1,2] ] )
>>> max(list)
```

Output 
[1, 4]

```
>>> min(list)
```

Output 
[-1, 2]